# detecting the maximum and minimum peaks of real-time pressure signal also calculating it

Tags: python, scipy

I am detecting in real time a pressure signal by a pressure sensor and try to plot it with pyqtgraph.
I managed to find the maxima of the signal by using the find_peaks function from scipy library.

```
    self.peaktimer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.peaktimer.setInterval(5000)
    self.peaktimer.timeout.connect(self.peak_calculator)
    self.peaktimer.start()

def update_plot_data(self):


    print(self.y)

    self.x = self.x[1:]  # Remove the first y element.
    self.x.append(self.x[-1] + 1)  # Add a new value 1 higher than the last.
    #self.x.append(measure)

    self.y = self.y[1:]  # Remove the first 
    self.y.append( randint(0,100))  # Add a new random value.
    #self.y.append( measuree)
    peaks.append(self.y)

    self.data_line.setData(self.x, self.y)  # Update the data.

# for finding highest peak values 
def peak_calculator(self):

    global peaks 

    self.indices = find_peaks(peaks, threshold=1)[0]

    print("result: ", len(self.indices))
    print("systolic", np.mean(self.indices)

    peaks = []
```

Is there a possibility to also find the minima(mimimum peaks value) with find_peaks?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with pyqtgraph since this library only has the task of displaying the information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes multiply `peaks` by `-1` this will have the effect of turning your signal upside-down whilst keeping the indices intact. That is the indices of the peaks found in `-peaks` give you the indices of the minima in `peaks` eg...

```
def peak_calculator(self):

    global peaks 
    self.indices = find_peaks(peaks, threshold=1)[0]

    peaks_min = peaks * -1
    indices_min = find_peaks(peaks_min, threshold=1)[0]
```

The heights of the peaks in either case can be found if you return the properties as well as the indices from `find_peaks()`

eg

```
indices, props = find_peaks(peaks, threshold=1)
maxima_heights = props[‘peak_heights’]
```

Comment: I understand the phenomena but It doesn't detect the low peaks values. I also wanted to print the highest peak values and lowest peak values

Comment: if you invert the signal, run the peak finder to get the indices of the peaks in the inverted signal then those indices will be the **same** indices for the minimal values in the original non-inverted signal

Comment: I have in my answer, `indices_min` contains the indices of the minimum peaks

Comment: I have given you all the information needed I'm not going to do the rest of the work for you